# What is the time complexity for this?

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity

```
nlog2n+3n^2+4n^3+n+10
```

from this polynomial what we supposed to consider either O(n^3) or O(logn)

from log2n we can have log2+logn right so it is logn .like wise

what we have to consider please tell me?

Comment: Why did you change your question to a completly different question? If you have something new to ask, please post a new question.

Comment: sorry Eran Bro..now i have asked as new question.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it's O(m*n), unless you have a typo and both your loops should iterate from 0 to n, in which case it would be O(n^2).